# Angular how to handle sequential requests and how handle loading var?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I save the profile and once the request would be sucess I make another request to create a payment. Right now the code lookes like this

```
 this.profileService.saveProfile(dataProfile).pipe(
      catchError(e => of(null))
    ).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) { // if user saved profile data
       const data = {
   params: {
            user: {
              surname: this.formInfo.get('surname').value,
              name: this.formInfo.get('name').value,
              father_name: this.formInfo.get('father_name').value,
              iin: this.formInfo.get('iin').value,
            },
            tariff: obj ? {
              months: obj.Months,
              amount: obj.Amount,
              amountByMonth: obj.AmountByMonth
            } : null,
}
        this.buyService.create(data).pipe( ... 
  }
```

What is the best way to make this code be better ? I have read about `concatMap` operator in `RXjs` but this is related to array of `Observables` , here I have only one response if user saved own data or not.
Also how should I  handle `loading` variable here for each request spearately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concatMap` is the operator to use most of the times to concatenate 2 or more http operations.

So, in this case, your code could look like this

```
this.profileService.saveProfile(dataProfile).pipe(
  concatMap(resp => {
     const data = {
        params: {
          // your params
        }
     }
     // the function passed to concatMap MUST return an Observable
     return this.buyService.create(data)
  })
).subscribe(
   next: result => {// manage the result},
   error: err => {// manage the error}
)
```

Honestly I do not understand when you write "*concatMap operator in RXjs but this is related to array of Observables*".

You may get some inspiration around typical http related use cases from [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Comment: well I mean that I use only the boolean response from```saveProfile``` , if user saved own data then I make another request. I was thinking that when I use ```concatMap``` I pass the data of first http req to the next http request.

Comment: You can ignore the data passed in by  the first service call, something like this `concatMap(() => {// do stuff; return this.buyService.create(data)})`. In this case you enter `concatMap` only if the previous request succeeds, otherwise you go into the `error` function specified as input to `subscribe`.